# How to change user credentials in Subclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, subclipse

I am using Subclipse (Subversion integration in Eclipse). I now want to change the user credentials in subclipse. How do I do that?
That is to login into subversion using another user account.

Answer (score 36):

Delete, or rename, the Eclipse '.keyring' file in Eclipse's configuration folder. This is where the Subclipse SVNKit connector caches your SVN credentials..

[ECLIPSE INSTALLATION]\configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.keyring

If, on the other hand, you're using the JavaHL connector -- or SVN command-line -- then their credentials are stored in the Subversion runtime config folder. Delete or rename the credential file.

On Windows:        %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth
On Linux and OSX:  ~/.subversion/auth

Sorry about this pig of complexity, for what should be a real version-control system.
:-(

Comment: in OSX 10.6, the keyring file can be found in the home directory with the name .eclipse_keyring rather than in the eclipse directory

Comment: For my install, the auth in question was under %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple

I used the file date to identify which to delete.

Comment: The CollabNet FAQ URL for this question is: http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/faq/clear_old_password.html

Answer (score 7):

If you want to flush the existing credentials, then look at this answer in the subversion wiki:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/PluginFAQ#head-d507c29676491f4419997a76735feb6ef0aa8cf8

If you're trying to checkout a repository under a specific username, but the repository is available read-only under a guest account, then there is no solution - you will have to do the checkout using the command line tool.
Even TortoiseSVN does not support this use-case.

Answer (score 7):

**You will find password files at:**
disk:\Documents and Settings\your_username\Application Data\Subversion\auth\svn.simple\

Remove the files and refresh the repository. **Subclipse will prompt you to enter username and password for your repository.**

Answer (score 6):

I struggled a lot on my Mac. Later found a simple solution.

1) Go to preference
[image]
2) Go to general and look for the security tab

3) Go into the content section & look for the repository
[image]

4) Delete the repository. It will automatically restart.

Alternatively, you can go to the secure_storage file under your home directory. Open it in the VI editor and remove the line for the corresponding repository. I would prefer the UI as it is simple.

(~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.equinox.security/secure_storage)

Answer (score 1):

In Mac OS X Lion, I found it stored in the Apple keychain

Answer (score 0):

As I'm using [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/), I can't check this, but it should be something along these lines:

1. Go to the *Preferences* screen
2. Under *Team*, *SVN*, select *Password management*
3. Remove the stored authentication data for the desired repository

You can also do it from your Subversion client, as the authentication data is stored in the `.svn` folders.

Comment: no,i am not using JAVAHL. In the case of JAVAHL,the data is stored in
~/.subversion/auth.

Comment: Which SVN connector are you using? It holds for SVN Kit, too: simply use the Subversion client to remove the authentication data (or supply a new username & password) and Subclipse should follow.

Comment: Just make sure to refresh your project.

Answer (score 0):

In SVN perspective, right click a repository and select *'Location Properties...'*. Edit *'Authentication'*, in General tab.